# Group posts by year, then by month

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help with LINQ-2-SQL in order to group some blog posts by a year and month.

Basically, I have a collection of blog posts that have the following properties

- Id
- Title
- Date

I want to be able to iterate through each year, then iterate through every month of that year, and finally, iterate through every blog post within that month. Something like

- 2011

  - April *(show number of posts)*

    - Random Post 1
    - Random Post 2
  - May *(show number of posts)*

    - Random Post 2

**etc...**

Is there a way I can do this with a single LINQ query, using the group by clause?

**Here's as far as I've got**

```
var groupedBlogPosts = (from p in blogPostsFiltered
                group p by new { month = p.Date.Month, year = p.Date.Year } into d
                select new { postDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}", d.Key.month, d.Key.year), postCount = d.Count() });
```

Comment: If you just want to list all of your blog posts in the indented format in your post it might just be easier to sort all of the posts by date and handle the indentation in a loop, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Unrelated, but you also might want to consider sorting months in descending order. So the most recent is on top.

Comment: Thanks @pickypg: I'll order as soon as I have the grouping sorted. @Chris, I think you might be missing something then, I don't quite understand how I'd group everything by looping through each post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't actually tested this, but it looks like a start, wrote this by looking at [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#nested):

```
var groupedBlogPosts =
                from p in blogPostsFiltered
                group p by p.Date.Year into yg
                select
                    new
                    {
                        Year = yg.Key,
                        MonthGroups =
                            from o in yg
                            group o by o.Date.Month into mg
                            select new { Month = mg.Key, Posts = mg }
                    };
```

Look under the `GroupBy - Nested` heading.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative if you don't want to do the projections and leave them as groupings.

```
var groupedBlogPosts =
    from post in blogPostsFiltered
    group post by new { post.Date.Year, post.Date.Month } into grouped
    group grouped by new { grouped.Key.Year };
```