# Nhibernate QueryOver - How to group by month?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Trying to get a total row count grouped by month and battling with QueryOver. From the limited resources I have found, seems like the clue is Projections.SqlGroupProjection yet I cannot get it right.

This is what I have so far:

```
var jobs = _statelessSession.QueryOver<Job>()
                .SelectList(list => list
                                        .Select(Projections.SqlGroupProjection("MONTH(DateCreated) AS Month", "MONTH(DateCreated)",new string[]{"DateCreated"},new[]{NHibernateUtil.Int32}))
                                        .SelectCount(m => m))
                .List<object>();
```

Comment: There is a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015732/group-by-month-and-year-parts-using-queryover

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Thanks. Did see that answer, but there is no code in the actual SqlGroupProjection in that answer - that is my issue

Answer (score 6):

Ended up with the following for future reference:

```
            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
            startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year,startDate.Month,1);
            var jobs = _session.QueryOver<Job>()
                .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.DateCreated).IsBetween(startDate).And(DateTime.Now)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(Projections.SqlGroupProjection(
                        "YEAR(DateCreated) As [Year]",
                        "YEAR(DateCreated)",
                        new[] { "YEAR" },
                        new IType[]{NHibernateUtil.Int32}))
                    .Select(Projections.SqlGroupProjection(
                        "MONTH(DateCreated) As [Month]",
                        "MONTH(DateCreated)",
                        new[] { "Month" },
                        new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 }))
                    .SelectCount(x=>x.Id))
                .OrderBy(Projections.SqlFunction(
                       "YEAR",
                       NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                       Projections.Property<Job>(item=>item.DateCreated))).Desc
                .ThenBy(Projections.SqlFunction(
                       "MONTH",
                       NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                       Projections.Property<Job>(item => item.DateCreated))).Desc
                .List<object>();
```

Which produced:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateCreated)  As [Year],
       MONTH(DateCreated) As [Month],
       count(this_.Id)    as y2_
FROM   Jobs this_
WHERE  this_.DateCreated between '2011-11-01T00:00:00.00' /* @p0 */ and '2012-05-07T14:23:52.00' /* @p1 */
GROUP  BY YEAR(DateCreated),
          MONTH(DateCreated)
ORDER  BY datepart(year, this_.DateCreated) desc,
          datepart(month, this_.DateCreated) desc
```

Answer (score 4):

you can by using the datepart functions, [have a look here](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/09/27/NHibernateQueryOverUsingDatepart.aspx) to see an example. Just to write some line here:

```
var result = session.QueryOver<Item>()
                .Where(
                Restrictions.Eq(
                Projections.SqlFunction("month"
                , NHibernateUtil.Int32
                , Projections.Property<Item>(item => item.StartDate)
                ) 
                ,1)).List();
```

the example suppose the Item entity as a property named StartDate. In [the post](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/09/27/NHibernateQueryOverUsingDatepart.aspx)  an example is given too on how to use the datepart projection even in reading data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try myself, just putting answers on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021177/27343) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381133/27343) together:

```
session.QueryOver<...>()
   .SelectList(list => list
      .Select(GroupProperty(Projections.SqlProjection(...)))
      .SelectSum(x => x.Price)
   );
```

+

```
group post by new { post.Date.Year, post.Date.Month } into grouped
```

=

```
.Select(GroupProperty(Projections.SqlProjection(
    new 
    { 
        post.Date.Year, 
        post.Date.Month 
    })))
```

**Edit**:

Another try:

```
   .SelectList(list => list
       .SelectGroup(c => c.Date.Year),
       .SelectGroup(c => c.Date.Month),
       .SelectCount(m => m))
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I can get the query to work using linq, but want to try and keep it within QueryOver<>